# How to return the result of llama_index's index.query(query, streaming=True)?

Tags: python, stream, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, llama-index

I am trying to return the result of llama_index's `index.query(query, streaming=True)`.

But not sure how to do it.

This one obviously doesn't work.

```py
index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk(index_file)

return index.query(query, streaming=True)
```

Error message: `TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object`.

This one neither.

```py
def stream_chat(query: str, index):
    for chunk in index.query(query, streaming=True):
        print(chunk)
        content = chunk["response"]
        if content is not None:
            yield content

# in another function
index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk(index_file)
return StreamingResponse(stream_chat(query, index), media_type="text/html")
```

Error message: `TypeError: 'StreamingResponse' object is not iterable`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

The answer is

```py
return StreamingResponse(index.query(query, streaming=True).response_gen)
```

Comment: If anyone is trying to figure out how to do this with a python Flask server, just wrap the response_gen object in the stream_with_context() Flask helper In your routed method: `return stream_with_context(index.query(query, streaming=True).response_gen)`

Comment: Does anyone have advice on how to implement this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flask, use [steam_with_context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.stream_with_context). The final code would be as shown below.

```
return stream_with_context(index.as_query_engine(streaming=True).query(user_prompt).response_gen)
```